# Stock price down on xetra and up on Nasdaq

Tags: stocks

I just checked the price of the stock I bought and is is down on Xetra -0,88 % ( where I bought it, as I wanted it in Euro) and up +0,38% on the nasdaq. Can the same stock actually go further this way and how far: up in one exchange and down in the other? I hope my question is clear enough. Thanks anyone for some insight. I am a beginner. Be kind :)

Comment: Have you looked at the Euro:Dollar exchange rate over the same period of time?

Comment: As well as checking the exchange rate you should check the Xetra close time - if you were looking at the close price it will be stale compared to the live quoting Nasdaq price

Comment: Thanks. Yes the price was stale compared to Nasdaq.. it is related to the time difference of openining market hours and therefore trading.